# How to extract specific field for all the objects who are in a list from JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract a specific field with it's value in JSON for every object that is in the list, so far I got it to work getting them one by one, but it needs to extract all of them if more objects with the same field are added to the JSON.

This is the JSON:

```
[{
    "took" : 1023,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
      "total" : 5,
      "successful" : 5,
      "skipped" : 0,
      "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
      "total" : 1,
      "max_score" : 114.88808,
      "hits" : [
        {
          "_index" : 1,
          "_type" : "doc",
          "_id" : 1,
          "_score" : 114.88808,
          "_source" : {
            "message" : "Error something happened"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "took" : 1023,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
      "total" : 5,
      "successful" : 5,
      "skipped" : 0,
      "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
      "total" : 1,
      "max_score" : 114.88808,
      "hits" : [
        {
          "_index" : 2,
          "_type" : "doc",
          "_id" : 2,
          "_score" : 114.88808,
          "_source" : {
            "message" : "Something else"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to get the values from the `message` field for both objects, so far as I mentioned I managed to do it one by one like that:

```
data = json.loads(open('test.json').read())
extracted_data = data[0]['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['message']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

below

```
data = [{
    "took" : 1023,
    "timed_out" : 'false',
    "_shards" : {
      "total" : 5,
      "successful" : 5,
      "skipped" : 0,
      "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
      "total" : 1,
      "max_score" : 114.88808,
      "hits" : [
        {
          "_index" : 1,
          "_type" : "doc",
          "_id" : 1,
          "_score" : 114.88808,
          "_source" : {
            "message" : "Error something happened"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "took" : 1023,
    "timed_out" : 'false',
    "_shards" : {
      "total" : 5,
      "successful" : 5,
      "skipped" : 0,
      "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
      "total" : 1,
      "max_score" : 114.88808,
      "hits" : [
        {
          "_index" : 2,
          "_type" : "doc",
          "_id" : 2,
          "_score" : 114.88808,
          "_source" : {
            "message" : "Something else"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
messages = [x['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['message'] for x in data]
print(messages)
```

output

```
['Error something happened', 'Something else']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
res = [y['_source']['message'] for x in data for y in x['hits']['hits']]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['Error something happened', 'Something else']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop would do the trick :

```
for d in data :
    extracted_data.append(d['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['message'])
```